# IRR() and XIRR() getting radically different results in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use Excel to calculate the IRR on a payment stream.  The payment amounts are irregular but they're almost all weekly with a few that vary from 4 to 10 days.  I got 121% using IRR().  Then I tried XIRR() expecting the result to be similar, but I get 234%.  I adjusted the payment dates to eliminate the irregularities and got 233%.  So why is it so different from IRR?  Here's the payment stream:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IRR` returns the nominal interest rate per period.  And it does not matter what the periods are so long as they are evenly spaced.

`XIRR` returns the effective annual interest rate.

Leaving aside the fact that `IRR` is not applicable since your payments are not even, you still have to convert nominal to effective in order to compare the outputs.

Merely multiplying the periodic return by 52 does not do that.

Using your data:

```
XIRR --> 234%
IRR --> 2.33%
IRR * 52 --> 121%
EFFECT(IRR*52,52) --> 232%
```

Answer (score 1):

`IRR()` function *doesn't know dates of payments* — it supposed regular **yearly** payments.

- *But this is not your case,* because your payments are performed about **weekly**.

`XIRR()` function, on the other hand, knows the *exact dates of your payments.*

Both these function return the **annual** rate of return, so there is no surprise that *weekly* payments produces *such high **annual** rate.*

(Daily payments would produce even *far higher* annual rates.)

Comment: I thought IRR() produced the periodic payment, so I multiplied the result by 52 periods.

Comment: Multiplying by 52 you got so called *annual* IRR — it's far away from the *annualized* IRR, when the calculation takes in consideration, that the annual rate produces a *different* result *after every payment* (because the base is changed).